# URL automatically apending to page URL

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to use a getElementsByTagName to swap out some text in the body section of my website and replace it with a hyperlink.  The problem is instead of giving me the link I'm specifying instead I get https://www.example.com/section1/"https://www.example.com/section2".

Here's my code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var string = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    var replacedString = string.replace(/msAb/gi,"<a href = &quot;https://www.example.com/sectiontitle&quot'>hyperlinktext</a>");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = replacedString;
}
</script>
```

I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `&quot;`? that's just to escape quotes not for like actual parameters

Comment: Try using \" instead of &quot;

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  They're both right and explained below.  I'm new to web development, so I was using &quot; based upon other similar questions... bad idea :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link element href values are normally supplied as quoted strings in HTML source. But in practice, and without suggesting you do so, the quotes can be omitted. So the HTML parser is going to remove quotes from around the href value if it sees them there. The HTML parser also replaces character entities like &quot; with the character the entity represents - in this case double quote marks.

The order in which the parser attempts to remove quote marks around the `href` attribute and replace character entities determines the result. You have amply demonstrated removing actual quote marks comes first. The `href` value, which ended up having quotation marks ***in*** it, after character entity replacement, is seen as a relative reference and produces the relative link you posted.

So take out the character entities from the string. Either escape the quotes in JavaScript with backslash, or use double quotes inside a single quoted string.

Comment: Thanks Traktor.  I came across the &quot; solution on another site, but needless to say it didn't work.  I saw somewhere that using \ to escape the double quote would not work properly, but the question was more complicated and somehow that related to it not interfacing properly with html.  Anyway, I tried both of your approaches, which work great!  I upvoted your answer, but I'm both new to web development and stackoverflow so it might not show up.  Thank you again for the help!

Comment: You didn't have the rep points to upvote - but you should be able to accept the answer. And you're welcome